# Issues building tess-two via osx command line

Tags: android, macos, bash, android-ndk, tesseract

I am currently attempting to build tess-two for an OCR android application via command line as instructed on https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two.  This is done on my macbook, OSX 10.9.4.

In order to build tess-two, this must be typed into command line:

> $ 1git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess
>
> $  cd tess
>
> $  cd tess-two
>
> $  ndk-build
>
> $  android update project --path .
>
> $  ant release

I encountered a problem as soon as I enter:

> $ android update project --path .

This is the error displayed:

> -bash: android: command not found

I have spend many hours trying to remedy this, and so far nothing fruitful has come of it. I appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the `android` command is not in your `PATH`. Try typing `which android`. It should give you the location if it is within your `PATH`.
Usually `android` can be found in your SDK directory under `tools`

You've got two options:

1. run the command with `your_sdk_path/tools/android update project --paht`
2. add android to your `PATH` with

   export PATH=$PATH:/your_sdk_path/tools

Answer (score 0):

You must have downloaded Android Development Toolkit bundle first. https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk#mac-bundle

Then add /sdk/tools to your path.

I hope you know how to configure your path. If you are not sure please have a look at this : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/